# linearlayout weight not working with vertical orientation

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am trying to divide whole screen into 3 buttons such that each button occupies full breadth of the screen and the length of the screen is divided equally between these buttons.
The graphical layout of the xml file is shown at https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSqVg.png

THIS XML CODE BELOW IS WORKING WHEN I USE ANDROID STUDIO. But when I use eclipse it does not work. It displays the content of fragment_main.xml.(hello world!)
What may be the reason due to which this could be happening?
I found that I could not use weights when linearlayout is in vertical orientation even for the simplest cases like the one shown in this example.

The xml code for this layout is-

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="3" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnButton1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="button 1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnButton2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="button 2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnButton3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="button 3" />



</LinearLayout>
```

But when I run the code in eclipse I get an empty screen. If I remove
android:layout_weight="1"
from every where in the xml file and change android:layout_height to 
android:layout_height="40dp"
(and removing android:weightSum="3" too) then it runs as shown in the graphical layout.

Comment: Try just removing the weightSum from the layout declaration, and leaving the child heights to 0dp and the weights to 1

Comment: Something is going on that we don't see. Your layout works as expected for me. You might try cleaning your project.

Comment: thanks codeMagic and zgc7009 for looking into my problem! I removed weightSum but the problem is still there. Cleaning the project didnt help either. @codeMagic would you mind sharing your apk file? Mine can be downloaded from here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/cq58ocfjqlmns6u/Linear.apk

Comment: Your layout xml is correct. Try cleaning your project and check that you are using the same layout which you are modifying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code that I have posted and also the one provided by Haresh Chhelana are both correct. I had not tested the xml file after running the app. I was looking at the preview which eclipse shows real time as we edit the xml file. It seems that there is a bug in eclipse due to which this error occurs. The xml file works perfectly fine when we use it in our application.